# Remove character inside TextInput while typing in it ? ( Flex 4.5 )

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I wish to remove specific characters inside Spark TextInput while user typing on it, without this causing any distrbance like licking with mouse after the last character or alike.

- Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Are those characters supposed to be there in first place? I mean, should the user be allowed to insert those "specific characters"? If not, try to use the [restrict](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#restrict) property from the TextInput to avoid unwanted characters, it's way easier.

Comment: they is supposed to be, but after a certain count of using them - they shall be prohibited, and lately removed the restriction.

Comment: But do you want to remove **all** occurrences of a specific character or only the ones **typed after** a certain limit? Can you provide a practical example?

Comment: nope. only the last one. but i think i found a way with keyUp event checkout, then remove whatever is not nessesary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom TextInput component and override the `keyDownHandler()` or you can add a event listener on the `TextInput`, like this:

```
<s:TextInput keyDown="{ textInputKeyDownHandler(event) }"/>
```

and then on the event handler:

```
private function textInputKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    // Make your validations and if necessary, use the following command 
    // to prevent the character from being added to the TextInput
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

This way the character will never be added to the `TextInput`, which means the *text* property and the cursor position will not change.

Note: Use the `event.charCode` and `event.keyCode` to make the necessary validations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restrict property of the TextInput? I don't know what are your specific characters, but commonly there are 2 cases of restriction.
Restrict to a set of characters:

```
<s:TextInput restrict="A-Za-z" />
```

Allow all characters except some special characters:

```
<s:TextInput restrict="^0-9" />
```

To deal with unicode characters, use \u:

```
<s:TextInput restrict="\u0239" />
```

Comment: it is restricted, but this is not the issue.